# How do i add a milimetric grid behind my graph

Tags: pgfplots, graphs, grids

So all i want is a milimetric grid that covers the graph and the axis. I haven't tried anything and don't know where to start from but here is the code for the graph itslef

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
height=0.8\textwidth,
xlabel={f},
ylabel={},
axis lines=left,
xmin=0, xmax=210,
ymin=0, ymax=9000,
xtick={10,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,170,200},
ytick={327.8 , 631.0 , 1775.7 , 2262.7 , 3115 , 3561.4 , 6240 , 8323.3 , 4156.6, 1552.5 , 1180.5 , 951.5},
legend pos=north west,
]

\addplot[
color=black,
mark=*
]
coordinates {
(10,327.8)(20,631.0)(40,1180.5)(60,1775.7)(80,2262.7)(100,3115)(120,3561.4)(140,4156.6)(170,6240)(200,8323.3)
};
\addplot[
color=black,
mark=*
]
coordinates {
(10,8323.3)(20,4156.6)(40,2262.7)(60,1552.5)(80,1180.5)(100,951.5)(120,796.5)(140,684.4)(170,558.1)(200,480.1)
};
\addplot[
color=red,
mark=*,
dashed
]
coordinates {
(56.5,1680)(56.5,0)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image: Graph image]

Comment: Welcome! Please complete your example with the needed `\documentclass` and the packages you use so that it's compilable by us; that will help us to help you. Thanks!

Comment: After providing the MWE : https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that, you can add `grid` in the brackets of `axis`